# Get rejection message from play store "Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection"

Tags: android, google-play, paytm

Recently upload my New app apk to play store. After upload I got an email that contains a warning:

"Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection."

unable to find out issue.. but after removing paytm payment gateway integration app approved.. but i need to add paytm payment gateway integration.
If any one has a similar problem and knows the solution for it, your help would be appreciated.

here is the mail

"*Hello Google Play Developer,

We reviewed your App, with package name com.xxxx.xxx, and found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.
Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Intent Redirection
Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.
*

Comment: Got the same issue. Did you find any alternative Payment Gateway?

Answer (score 2):

The issue has been fixed in the latest version of All-in-One SDK. Please use the version 1.5.3.

`implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.5.3'`

Comment: Thank goodness. I have been really frustrated. I didn't use Intents at all in my application and I get an intent redirection vulnerability?I was like wtf

Comment: This worked like charm. I have been in similar situations twice before and both times it was Paytm's SDK (might be other payment libraries as well).